# If $A$ is a positive operator and $B$ is a bounded operator, show that $B^*AB$ is positive.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $A$ is a positive operator and $B$ is a bounded operator, show that $B^*AB$ is positive.  Where both $A$ and $B$ are operators in a Hilbert space $H$.

I know that if $A$ is a positive operator, that it implies that $A$ is also self-adjoint and that $\langle x,Ax\rangle\geq 0$.  Then $A^*A=I$, but I'm not sure where I can go from here.  Can I just say that since $A^*=A$ then $BA^*=BA$?  But then where to go?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $A$ also bounded? Consider $\langle B^\ast AB x,x\rangle$.

Comment: $A^* A = I$ is not true!

Answer (score 2):

Take arbitrary $x$, then we have
$(x,B^*ABx)=(Bx,ABx)=((Bx),A(Bx))\ge 0$ since $A$ is positive

Comment: Boundedness of $B$ not necessary?